# Digispark: check if the USB host is connected

Tags: digispark

I am trying to detect if the digispark device is actually connected to a host (i.e. the USB line is "active") vs. just powered.
The issue: if I send a keypress while the data line is disconnected, the code hangs perpetually in [`sendKeyPress`](https://github.com/digistump/DigistumpArduino/blob/111396ffe5163c3613b9315cbea1a3eabc9ba6dc/digistump-avr/libraries/DigisparkKeyboard/DigiKeyboard.h#L188).
My theory is that it keeps looping in while waiting for USB to be ready, which makes sense.

```
    while (!usbInterruptIsReady()) {
      // Note: We wait until we can send keyPress
      //       so we know the previous keyPress was
      //       sent.
        usbPoll();
        _delay_ms(5);
    }
```

I tried to use the macro `usbInterruptIsReady()` before calling `sendKeyStroke` in the `main`, but with no success. I would expect to see a function that keeps track of this state, but apparently there is none.

Also: it doesn't seem like what I am trying to accomplish being extremely weird, so my expectation is that someone else could have stumbled upon this and figured out a reasonable workaround.
I would like to avoid setting up a watchdog timer.

Code below for example hangs when the device is powered but not connected to a PC.
Thanks

Background: https://hackaday.io/project/191762-automatic-workstation-locker

```
#include "DigiKeyboard.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  DigiKeyboard.update();

  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);
}

void loop() {
  static uint8_t bit = 0;
  bit = 1 - bit;
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, bit);
  DigiKeyboard.update();
  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_Q);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: I've deleted all the comments which had descended into sledging. Please remember, comments under the question are for clarifying it, not attacking each other.

Comment: If you wish to complain about the way this site is working please raise an issue on [our Meta site](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The question looks reasonable to me, however @Paperino you should not keep re-posting the same question. Try to salvage the original one where possible. As it is now deleted I suggest we run with this one.

Answer (score 0):

The Digispark does not have a proper hardware USB implementation. It is possible that you simply can't do what you are attempting to do. A search I did indicated you are not the only person attempting to do this.

You may want to switch to one of the Arduinos that have a hardware USB interface like the Leonardo or Micro.

I should point out that the Digispark is not an Arduino, and it has [its own forum](http://digistump.com/board/) where you may possibly get an answer from their own community.